# Workflow UI and back end Design and Technology

Tags: javascript, java, python, architecture, software-design

**Requirement:**
I have a requirement to design a Work Flow to control movement of a test robot. The APIs for controlling the robot is exposed, which I need to call based on the structure defined in the workflow. Workflow defines the movements to be performed in sequence.

**WorkFlow example:**
[Start] -> [Move to X,Y,Z coordinate] -> [Move to X,Y,Z coordinate] -> [Move Down to X distance] -> [Move Up to X distance] -> [End]

Each block in the above workflow will have "action" (Move) and "values"(Coordinates) to be set for each action and the backend will takes these values, do some calculations and call the APIs for moving the robot with the calculated value.

**Design:**
I am a java developer as of now , open to try Python .I needed some ideas related to which Technology to be used for Frontend as well as Backend, and a rough design suggestion
OR
 
is there any open source which is already doing something similar, which I can either refer or use.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the design of the flow, I would create a template file which can support a standard structure which can be interpreted (XML, JSON etc) which can be sent to the back-end by the UI, based on which the trigger for `START` should take place, with the steps of `MOVE` and at the final one `END` being outlined within the same structure.

That way, when the request to the back-end is being processed, it is being broken down within its logic in the steps specified, calling the Test Robot's API sequentially for each of them.

So a sample of a JSON request for example would look like:

```
{
  "automated_request": {
    "start": true,
    "steps": [
      "step": {
        "name": "First Step"
        "action": "Move",
        "parameters":[
          "coordinates":{"x": 10, "y": 20}
        ]
      }
      "step": {
        "name": "Second Step"
        "action": "Move",
        "parameters":[
          "coordinates":{"x": 10, "y": 30}
        ]
      }
    ]
    "end": true
  }
}
```

or you can even customize the `step` object so that it encompasses even more complex information.

Either way, I would suggest you encapsulate the workflow information within the request to something that can support an organized structure, which can then be broken down within the workflow steps when its being processes by the back-end.